# mongodb - how to pass a variable field in geoNear?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

coordinates are stored in array

```
const userLocArray = userLoc.split(',');
```

How to use this array in geoNear coordinates?

**userLocArray[0], userLocArray[1] does not work**

```
$geoNear: {
   near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [userLocArray[0], userLocArray[1]] },
   distanceField: "calculatedDist",
   spherical: true
}
```

On the client side:

```
       const userLoc = currentUser.location.coordinates;
        console.log(userLoc)//this is [31.4998, -61.4065]
let { data: matches } = useSWR(`/api/myapi?userIdToMatch=${_id}&userLoc=${userLoc}&page=${matchIndex}`, fetcher,);
```

In the api

```
handler.get(async (req, res) => {
  const {userIdToMatch, userLoc} = req.query;
  const userLocArray = userLoc.split(',');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coordinates` is an array of numbers, you are passing `strings`. Try this:

```
$geoNear: {
   near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [parseFloat(userLocArray[0]), parseFloat(userLocArray[1])] },
   distanceField: "calculatedDist",
   spherical: true
}
```

You can also use `Number` instead of `parseFloat`.

Comment: This shows an error - `invalid argument in geo near query: type`

Comment: Can you share a value of `userLoc`? If possible with some additional code how the query is getting triggerd

Comment: sure - added client side and api code

Comment: The query is syntactically correct. Check here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/1P8W5DkFXlk. It only complains about indexes. Are you sure that the arrays match on the client and API sides?

Comment: I agree query is correct except when I replace the numbers in the coordinates with a variable `userLoc[0]` it shows errors. Hard coding integers in the query works for me too.

Comment: That is strange, if possible please share the whole query that is written on the API side in the question

Comment: There was probably a syntax error in my coordinates query. Now parseFloat seems to work. Thanks

Comment: Can you help me start this query in mongo playgound (in question) from `user's` collection? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73910975/mongodb-how-to-sort-by-distance-using-geonear-in-addition-to-looking-up-anothe